# Как на фронтенде получить объект находящийся в сессии?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Передаю объект представлению через сессию, не могу понять как в jquery с у него вытащить параметры.
В котроллере передаю объект:

```
Session["object"] = objectTR;//Некоторый объект
```

В представлении пытаюсь получить из него параметры. Но не получается(

```
@model IEnumerable<...Models.TrainingObject>
TrainingObject traingObj = (TrainingObject)@HttpContext.Current.Session["object"];
traingObj.number;
traingObj["number"];
```

Но все равно все пусто. Как можно получить параметры из объекта в сессии

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@{Models.TrainingObject traingObj = (Models.TrainingObject)HttpContext.Current.Session["object"];}
<script>
var traingObj_Number = @traingObj.number;
console.log(traingObj_Number);
</script>
```

Comment: Когда я вписал как у вас он начал писать что TrainingObject  не найден

Comment: @chilo5432 добавьте namespace